# How to use a .svg file in Material-UI Avatar component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an svg file that I want to use within mui avatar component but
Doing this `<Avatar src="./**.svg" />` does not render (blank).
While this `<Avatar src="./**.png" />` works.
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a SvgIcon component based on the .svg file and next you could use that component in the Avatar to show the icon.

I will show you an example step by step:

1. [Download the .svg file to be used in the example](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined:add_circle_outline:)
2. Create the SvgIcon component in a .tsx file based on the downloaded file. All the path tags are important:

   ```
   import * as React from "react";
   import SvgIcon, { SvgIconProps } from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

   const AddCircleOutlineIcon: React.FC<SvgIconProps> = (props) => (
       <SvgIcon {...props}>
           <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
           <path d="M13 7h-2v4H7v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4V7zm-1-5C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/>
       </SvgIcon>);

   export default AddCircleOutlineIcon;
   ```
3. Add the icon component created in the Avatar:

   ```
   <Avatar>
       <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
   </Avatar>
   ```
4. [Icon Avatar Doc](https://mui.com/components/avatars/#IconAvatars.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate component for SVG and pass it a child for SVG as per the documentation present in
https://mui.com/components/avatars/

```html
<Avatar>
  <SVGComponent />
</Avatar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SVG stored locally, you can use `import {ReactComponent as YourSvg} from 'path/to/svg'` and simply use it as a component.

```
<Avatar>
  <YourSvg />
</Avatar>
```

You could also import your SVG and use it as the src

```
import AvatarSvg from 'path/to/svg'

<Avatar src={AvatarSvg} />
```